# itegrable, converge, improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

$f(x)$ is a itegrable function on $(0,+\infty)$ and $\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$  coverge. Prove that $$\lim_{t\to 0^+}{\int_{0}^{+\infty }e^{-tx}f(x)dx}=\int_{0}^{+\infty }f(x)dx$$

I got  that problem when I learned about improper-integals with a parameter.  $\int_{x\to 0^+}^{+\infty}e^{-tx}f(x)dx$ is uniformly converge but $f(x)$ is not continuous (if we had, it would be easier).

Answer (score 1):

**BIG Hint**

When $t>0$, 
$$|e^{-tx}f(x)|\leq |f(x)|.$$

**Second way (without DCT)**

$$|f(x)e^{-tx}-f(x)|=|f(x)||e^{-tx}-1|.$$
Using [MVT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem), $$|e^{-tx}-1|\leq |t|\underset{t\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0,$$
and thus, the convergence is uniform (in $x$). Therefore, you can permute limit and integral.

Comment: So the left integral uniformly converge but $f(x)$ is just integrable

Comment: No ! Use [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) !

Comment: Thank you :)  but I haven't learned about that. Can you prove more easily?

Comment: @Noun: I edited my answer.

Comment: Can you add a link which is about permuting limit and integral, please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence

Comment: You mean $lim_{n\to+\infty}\int_{0}^{+\infty }f(x)(e^{-t_nx})dx=\int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)dx$ with $t_n$ is a sequence comes to $0$, don't you? I can prove overall $b>0$  but for $+\infty $.